# Julia Lang If Statement issue

Tags: arrays, if-statement, julia

I have been trying to run a code similar to the following but the evaluation hangs on and consumes all the pc memory.... What I'm doing wrong?

```
function db(v)
c=0;
r=0;
i=1;
while i<=lastindex(v)
    if v[i]==0
        c=c+1
    else
     r=r+1
    end
end
return c;
return r;
end

r=[1,0,4,5,0,0,7];
```

db(r) > hogs the memory an no result....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an infinite loop because you never change `i`. Do you want something like what I have below?

```
function db(v)
    c=0;
    r=0;
    for x in v
        if x==0
            c=c+1
        else
            r=r+1
        end
    end
    return c,r;
end
```